Does the TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CCM ciphersuite support the sha 384 hash function?
In TLS 1.2, do the TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CCM and TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CCM_8 ciphersuites support the SHA-384 or SHA-512 hash functions?

This is specified in the informational RFC 7251 where is states in Appendix A

An implementation that includes either
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CCM or
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CCM_8 SHOULD support [...] the SHA-384 hash function, and MAY support [...] the SHA-512 hash function.


Thanks Daniel, in this case how the server & client negotiates for which hash algorithm to be used (say both sha 384 and Sha 512) supported

By using the hash field of a SignatureAndHashAlgorithm  part of a signature_algorithms extension to a Hello. See section 7.4.1.4.1 of RFC 5246 (TLS1.2)
